# Java Recursive function behavoir

Tags: java, algorithm, huffman-code

I finished developing a BinaryTree class in Java that builds a Huffman-style binary tree/map to "encode" a phrase into a binary value.

Some of the methods use recursion to populate/traverse the nodes of the tree.  I have a method that encodes a string, say `test` to `01111110001`.  In order to encode it, I have a function that maps the path of the tree to the node with that character.  I also have a function that searches the nodes to find the leaf node of that character.

Everything is working fine: the tree is built, I can search and locate nodes, and the mapping works.  When I output the node parameter for the `searchNode` method, it looks like the code is traversing the tree okay... but it doesn't quit after it finds the node.  It finds it multiple times. I have made a few different variations of the method(s) and I can't get it to quit either traversing the entire tree, or stopping once it finds the node the ***first time***.

I'm wondering why the code won't stop after finding the node the first time, and looking for any suggestions on how to optimize it.

```
public class BinaryTree {

        ---snip ---

            /*
             * searchNode
             * Searches nodes for a value
             *
             * @param n Node to start or focus at
             * @param c char character to search for
             * @return Node containing value
             */
            public Node searchNode(Node n, char c) {
                System.out.println(n);
                if(n != null) {
                    if(n._char == c) { return n; }
                    if(this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c) != null) {
                        return this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c);
                    }
                    if(this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c) != null) {
                        return this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }






            /*
             * mapPath
             * Maps path with 1s or 0s from root node to
             * node containing char
             *
             * @param n Node to map to
             * @return StringBuilder string of map
             */
            public StringBuilder mapPath(Node n) {
                if(n == null) { return new StringBuilder(1); }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
                if(n == this._root || n._parent == null) {
                    sb.insert(0, "0");
                    return sb;
                }
                Node p = n._parent;
                while(p != null) {
                    if(p._leftChild == n) {
                        sb.insert(0, "0");
                    } else {
                        if(p._rightChild == n) {
                            sb.insert(0, "1");
                        }
                    }
                    n = p;
                    p = p._parent;
                }

                return sb;

            }




            /*
             * encodeString
             * Encodes a string with appropriate binary value
             *
             * @param s String to encode
             * @returns encoded String(Builder)
             */
            public StringBuilder encodeString(String s) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 10);
                char[] st = s.toCharArray();
                for(char stt : st) {
                    sb.append(this.mapPath(this.searchNode(this._root, stt)));
                }
                return sb;
            }





            /**
             * @param args the command line arguments
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree(args[0]);
                bt.buildTree();
                System.out.println(bt.searchNode(bt._root, args[1].toCharArray()[0]));
                //System.out.println(bt.encodeString(args[1]));
            }

        }
```

The first argument is the phrase or data to encode.  The second argument I am passing is the character to search for so `java BinaryTree this\ is\ a\ test a` uses "this is a test" for the tree and searches for 'a'.

The tree looks like

```
      14
    /    \
   6      8
  / \     / \
 s  t    _   5
            / \
           i   3
              / \
             a   2
                / \
               h  e
```

When I run `java BinaryTree this\ is\ a\ test i` I get the following output:

```
_ - 14[parent=null *root*]
_ - 6[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]
s - 3[parent=_ - 6[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
null
null
t - 3[parent=_ - 6[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
null
null
_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]
  - 3[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
null
null
_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]
  - 3[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
null
null
_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
```

The output includes the parents of the node to help me visualize the tree while debugging.

You can see that it found the character 'i' 9 times. Yet when it encodes the string/characters it translates fine to 110.

Comment: i - 2[parent=_ - 5[parent=_ - 8[parent=_ - 14[parent=null *root*]]]]
Not missing here 3 Node?

Comment: No because 3 isn't the parent of the 'i' leaf node.  The value of the node is 2 (thats why you see `i - 2`.  The immediate parent is the 5 node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't stop the first time you find the node, because you keep on searching after finding it.

```
if(this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c) != null) {
    return this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c);
}
if(this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c) != null) {
    return this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c);
}
```

if `this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c)` finds the node (and returns a non-`null` result), then you immediately redo the search to return the value.  Starting at the root, it will (eventually) search right, to the 8 node, then the 5 node, then search left from the 3 node.  Then it will search left from the 3 node again, returning to the 5 node with non-null.  The 5 node repeats the search (because it got a non-null value), so you search the 3 node again, find the value, search again (to get the return value), which is returned, and returned again to the 8 node.  The 8 node gets a non-null value, and so searches again to return the value (so we visit the 5, and 3, and 3, and 5, and 3 and 3) and return to the root, which again searches the 8 (5 & 3 & 3 and 5 & 3 & 3) and returns.

You want to save your found value, so you can return it!

```
Node result;
result = this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c);
if (result != null)
   return result;
result = this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c);
if (result != null)
   return result;
```

Alternately:

```
Node result = null;

if (n != null) {
    ...
    result = this.searchNode(n._leftChild, c);
    if (result == null)
        result = this.searchNode(n._rightChild, c);
}
return result;
```